# Calling Python from an open excel file to make real-time changes

Tags: excel, pandas, xlwings

I have python code that pulls stock data from the Yahoo API.  It takes the ticker symbols from an excel spreadsheet using this code and creates a list of ticker symbols.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\yahoo.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') 
tickers = df['Ticker'].tolist()
```

The remaining code feeds the tickers to the Yahoo API and populates the other columns. It works fine if I close the excel file before I run the Python code. Instead I would like to be able to change symbols and call the python code without closing the excel file and see the changes in real-time but it won't let me because the file is locked while it's open. I read that it may be possible using xlwings to work with an open excel file. I downloaded the xlwings program for python and excel.  I've had no luck getting it working.  Is it possible to accomplish this or am I wasting time?

Full Code

```
import yfinance as yf
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor  

list_of_futures= []

def get_stats(ticker):
    info = yf.Tickers(ticker).tickers[ticker].info
    cols = ['sector', 'industry', 'currentPrice', 'marketCap', 'forwardPE', 'sharesOutstanding','totalRevenue', 'netIncomeToCommon','fullTimeEmployees','totalCash','totalDebt','bookValue','fiftyTwoWeekHigh','fiftyTwoWeekLow','grossMargins', 'operatingMargins', 'profitMargins', 'freeCashflow',
            'ebitda','grossProfits','priceToBook','fiftyDayAverage','twoHundredDayAverage','exchange','forwardEps','trailingEps','volume','averageVolume10days','heldPercentInstitutions','targetMeanPrice','returnOnEquity','shortName']
    return {'ticker': ticker, **{c: info[c] for c in cols}}     
    
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\jkru0\OneDrive\Desktop\yahoo.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1') 
tickers = df['Ticker'].tolist()

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    result_iter = executor.map(get_stats, tickers)

df = pd.DataFrame(result_iter)

df.columns = ['Ticker', 'Sector', 'Industry', 'Price', 'MarketCap', 'ForwardPE', 'SharesOutstanding', 'Total Revenue', 'NetIncometoCommon', 'FullTimeEmployees', 'Total Cash', 'Total Debt', 'Book Value', '52Wk High', '52Wk Low', 'Gross Margins', 'Operating Margins', 'Profit Margins', 'FreeCashFlow',
              'Ebitda', 'Gross Profits', 'PricetoBook', '50DayAvg', '200DayAvg', 'Exchange', 'ForwardEPS', 'TrailingEPS','Volume','averageVolume10days','heldPercentInstitutions','targetMeanPrice','ROE', 'Comp Name']

df.to_excel("yahoo.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Using UDFs might help you with what you want to achieve. You can have a read about it here https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html